# RelativeLayout Visibility is not working when using View.GONE

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, view

I have a parent RelativeLayout, that have other Views and other Relative Layouts inside of it. When I try to make one of these RelativeLayouts have a `GONE` visibility, it just won't disappear. Any solution for this? I'll post the layout I want `GONE`.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayerA"
     android:layout_width="315px"
     android:layout_height="35px"
     android:background="@drawable/bgnavyblue_abcd"
     android:layout_below="@id/relativeConfig1"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/relativeRecipe"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
     android:layout_marginTop="20px"
     >                 

     <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIconA"
         android:layout_width="33px"
         android:layout_height="33px"                                            
         android:src="@drawable/icon_a"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" <!--  -->
         />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/txtLayerA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/layer_a_adjusts"
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgIconA"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginTop="8px"               
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the whole code: http://pastebin.com/VhpWSa6Z
Please, anyone know whats going on?

EDIT: Someone said that this might be happening because other View is using this View to position itself at the screen. So I tried to set `GONE` visibility to the RelativeLayerC. And it worked. I don't get it why it works with this View, and not with RelativeLayerA. Here you can see the RelativeConfig4 using RelativeLayerC as reference. http://pastebin.com/uHW6faPy

Comment: you can put ImageView and textView within the frame layout

Comment: That's a lot of stuff to have in one view. I recommend maybe adding some new views, putting some of this stuff in each, and using intents to switch to them as needed.

Comment: where exactly are you trying to GONE this layout?

Comment: @JosephusVillarey, I'm trying to make it gone at the onCreate method.

I need this Relative Layout because I need one specific location with a different background color. The whole background is black, but there is a specific location that I need it blue.

Comment: @BjornTipling, this is what I'm going to do, because I'll have more stuff in this xml file. I have like 18 screens, but most of them have the same things, with different orders at the views. So I'm using only 1 xml file and I'll use intents to change between the screens.

Comment: It's kind of insane. Maybe use fragments. Many smaller XML files are better than a giant one. You can reuse layouts.

Comment: Well for some weird reason my RelativeLayerA couldn't be `GONE` because it was used as reference. What I really don't get it is why the others are used as references as well, but can be `GONE`. Anyway, thank you for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem.. I think it's a bug.. :(
You can bypass it though.. try this to make the RelativeLayout invisible.

```
RelativeLayout rLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.//your relativeLayout id);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    0, // its height... set it 0 to make it invisible..
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT // and its width
);
rLayout.setLayoutParams(rParams);
```

This to make it visible.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

rLayout.setLayoutParams(rParams);

Here are the correct parameters for RelativeLayout in xml.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#AA000000" >
```

Remember! dont use this.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

or left, right.. otherwise it will not work..!

Hope that helps.